# Shrinking header on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery which applies a class to my fixed header to shrink it when the user is scrolled any distance down the page:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1){
    $('div.single-level-nav').addClass("shrunk");
  }
  else{
    $('div.single-level-nav').removeClass("shrunk");
  }
});
```

This is working, but of course is constantly firing whenever the user is scrolling. This seems a bit of overkill, and not a great use of resources.

What I have may be the best way of achieving what I want, but I was wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: You should provide a complete and functional example.

Comment: To me this feels like a question asking for [advice about code not yet written](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/3651), and those are off-topic. Please [follow the tour](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) and read ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Just simplify the condition: `if (window.scrollY > 1)`. BTW there's `toggleClass` in jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

```js
// init your element
var $nav = $('div.single-level-nav');
// use a boolean var to check if the element is already shrinked
var navShrinked = false;

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1){
    // add class only once
    if(!navShrinked) {
      $nav.addClass("shrunk");
      navShrinked = true;
    }
  }
  else{
    // remove class only once
    if(navShrinked) {
      $nav.removeClass("shrunk");
      navShrinked = false;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1500px;
}
.single-level-nav {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  transition: height .3s;
}
.single-level-nav.shrunk {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="single-level-nav"></div>
</body>
</html>
```